# Optimal filtering of the manytomany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, orm

I have a model called "Car" and another model called "Preference". The car field has a M2M relationship with "Preference".

I am doing a query to get all the cars that have the preference (for example) with id= 1 and 2. (The car has many more preferences assigned to it). How can I get optimally all the cars that have strictly the Preferences with id 1 and 2?

The actual functional code is the following (very suboptimal):

```
 preferences_list = [1, 2]
 for preference_item in preferences_list:
     cars = cars.objects.filter(preferences__id=preference_item)
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work either:

```
 preferences_list = [1, 2]
 cars_q = Q()
 for preference_item in preferences_list:
     cars_q &= Q(preferences__id=preference_item)
 cars=cars.objects.filter(cars_q)
```

Is there any more optimal alternative that does not do a query for each Preference?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#in) to check if given field exists in iterable:

```
preferences_list = [1, 2]
cars = Cars.objects.filter(preferences__in=preferences_list)
```

Comment: "In" is not the solution. An __in acts as an OR, so it would return cars that have one preference or the other. I need it to return cars that have both preferences.